# Insert data and fill columns with rank

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update, mysql-5.5

**original data: orginal_table**

```
MID STATE CALL_TIME         RECORD_RANK
a   1    2020-12-18 09:00:00        1
a   2    2020-12-19 09:00:00        2
b   1    2020-12-18 09:00:02        1
c   1    2020-12-18 09:00:03        1
c   1    2020-12-19 09:00:03        2
c   1    2020-12-20 09:00:03        3
d   1    2020-12-19 09:00:00        1
```

**The data I wanted to insert: insert_table**

```
   MID  STATE      CALL_TIME  
   a    2     2020-12-30 09:00:00      
   b    2     2020-12-19 09:00:02   
   c    1     2020-12-21 09:00:03 
   e    1     2020-12-30 09:00:00 
   f    1     2020-12-30 09:00:00 
   f    2     2020-12-31 09:00:00
```

Goal

- The original data will be inserted from the second data.
- For original and inserted data, the pair `MID and CALL_TIME` is unique.
- There is no `RECORD_RANK` column in the inserted data but `RECORD_RANK` will be calculated based on `MID and CALL_TIME columns` when inserted. When duplicated MID with different CALL_TIME, the value of RECORD_RANK with MID will be added by 1. The initial value is 1.
- The earliest row in in insert_table is always later than the latest row in orginal_table with the same MID.

The expected example result as below:

```
MID  STATE      CALL_TIME         RECORD_RANK
a    1    2020-12-18 09:00:00        1
a    2    2020-12-19 09:00:00        2
b    1    2020-12-18 09:00:02        1
c    1    2020-12-18 09:00:03        1
c    1    2020-12-19 09:00:03        2
c    1    2020-12-20 09:00:03        3
d    1    2020-12-19 09:00:00        1
a    2    2020-12-30 09:00:00        3
b    2    2020-12-19 09:00:02        2  
c    1    2020-12-21 09:00:03        4
e    1    2020-12-30 09:00:00        1
f    1    2020-12-30 09:00:00        1 
f    2    2020-12-31 09:00:00        2
```

**Note**

- mysql version: 5.5.47-log

Comment: If call_times are always increasing, I see no need to store record_rank. Just calculate it when you need it

Comment: Incidentally, by convention, the term 'id' implies a surrogate PRIMARY KEY. That's not the case here so it might be an idea to rename that column.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy  No, any value of ID could be duplicated.

Comment: @Strawberry, I changed 'ID' to 'MID'.

Comment: Does the ealiest row in `insert_table` is always later than the latest row in `orginal_table` with the same `MID`? i.e. does the `RECORD_RANK` values already present in `orginal_table` wil be recalculated never?

Comment: @Akina yes, the earliest row in in insert_table is always later than the latest row in orginal_table with the same MID.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, Akina's trigger provides a way to set `MID` for _future_ `INSERTs`.  (It does not take care of the rank changing due to deletes or updates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to handle the logic in a single `insert`, even in MySQL 5.x.

The target rank is the number of rows that already exists in the target table for the same `mid`, plus the number of `mid` rows in the source table prior to the current row. You can compute that with correlated subqueries:

```
insert into orginal_table (mid, state, call_time, record_rank)
select mid, state, call_time,
    1 + (
        select count(*)
        from orginal_table o
        where o.mid = i.mid
    ) + (
        select count(*) 
        from insert_table i1 
        where i1.mid = i.mid and i1.call_time < i.call_time
    ) as record_rank
from insert_table i
```

This assumes that all new rows are more recent that existing rows, as mentioned in your question. But if you want otherwise, that's an easy fix to the first subquery:

```
(
    select count(*)
    from orginal_table o
    where o.mid = i.mid and o.call_time < i.call_time
)
```

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=e4c541896ba8a3926e0c335311e65b9f)** based on the nice test case built by Akina.

Side note: in MySQL 8.0, we would use a window function instead of the second subquery, which would make the query much more efficient:

```
insert into orginal_table (mid, state, call_time, record_rank)
select mid, state, call_time,
    row_number() over(partition by mid order by call_time) 
    + (
        select count(*)
        from orginal_table o
        where o.mid = i.mid
    ) as record_rank
from insert_table i
```

Answer (score 3):

If the ealiest row in `insert_table` is always later than the latest row in `orginal_table` with the same `MID` then you may use BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_original
BEFORE INSERT
ON orginal_table
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.RECORD_RANK = (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) + 1
                       FROM orginal_table
                       WHERE NEW.MID = orginal_table.MID)
```

After trigger creation you may simply add new rows by

```sql
INSERT INTO orginal_table
SELECT *, NULL FROM insert_table;
```

New values for `RECORD_RANK` will be added by the trigger.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bed8d5b43a50fdf4f239e137652c1090)

---

If the rows from both tables will mix and `RECORD_RANK` for some rows which are already present in `orginal_table` must be altered then the operation cannot be performed using one query (because both insert for new rows and update for existing ones needed). In this case I recommend to insert the rows with any (NULL) value for `RECORD_RANK` column, then recalculate the column value for all rows in a table.

Comment: I guess we just see it differently

Comment: Why? The OP will be operating under the principle of confirmation bias.

Comment: @Akina is it necessary to use trigger?

Comment: @jack No, of course, you may use any other method. But its usage simplifies the process, it seems.

Comment: @Akina - Your cleaver technique might be improved by changing `COUNT(*)` to `MAX(mid)`?

Comment: @RickJames ??? ... fiddle is avaliable - you may try.

Comment: @Akina "INSERT INTO orginal_table" without (column1, column2, column3, ...)   seems risky if I just want to insert specific columns like GMB 's script . And I do not know your script because I do not know how to use trigger. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Jack *seems risky* If your data for insertion may be wrong (may have wrong structure) then add columns list - no problems. *I do not know how to use trigger.* The fiddle demanstrates this completely. Please do not ask general question, point to the place which is not clear for you.